# What does "Visit Waypoint" in missions mean?

Tags: ingress

The new "Missions" feature has some mission steps called "Visit Waypoint". What does that mean? How do you visit waypoints?

I've tried a mission yesterday and couldn't clearly figure out what it meant. Some waypoints were completed automatically in a few seconds after walking into the waypoints but some didn't. I had to press on the waypoint markers and open the linked Fieldtrip page to complete them and one of them even reacted more strangely: I had to select the waypoint marker and press on "Navigate" to finally complete it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A waypoint is a designated location, usually one of several that you need to visit in order to complete the mission. Field Trip locations require you to open the "card" that links to the Field Trip page in order to complete.

Depending on the particular mission, the order in which you visit each waypoint might also be important, so you may find that they don't complete when visited out of the listed order (these ones are marked "complete waypoints in sequence" on the Details screen). Sometimes the order is hidden and linked by clues (and some require actions to be performed, such as using the "Navigate" function).

Source: [Google - Experience Ingress Missions](https://support.google.com/ingress/answer/6099278?hl=en)

Source: [The Verge - Google's 'Ingress' will soon let players build scavenger-hunt missions across the globe](http://www.theverge.com/2014/9/25/6840157/google-ingress-scavenger-hunt-missions-launch)

Comment: Not exactly what I was asking for but thanks anyway. I'm already aware of the Google's missions page but it doesn't contain how "visiting a waypoint" is accomplished. Yesterday I was able to visit some waypoints without interacting with the "Navigate" button or pressing on them on the radar and opening the linked "Field Trip" page so my question still remains the same: What's the proper way to visit waypoints?